# struts datagrid problem - can't solve this problem

Tags: datagrid, struts

i am creating datagrid using the struts-layout. and i encountered this problem

javax.servlet.ServletException: DispatchMapping[/monitor/datagridBL]でハンドラプロパティが定義されていません
    at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.getParameter(DispatchAction.java:325)
    at org.apache.struts.actions.DispatchAction.execute(DispatchAction.java:170)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
    at jp.terasoluna.fw.web.struts.action.RequestProcessorEx.process(RequestProcessorEx.java:149)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1196)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:292)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at jp.co.anicom.fw.web.common.controller.RequestEncodeFilter.doFilter(RequestEncodeFilter.java:42)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at jp.co.anicom.fw.web.common.controller.SessionExpirationFilter.doFilter(SessionExpirationFilter.java:89)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3588)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2200)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2106)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1428)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)

i have been looking for ways on how to solve this. would somebody help me please...

Answer (score 0):

Check if your action file (type=xxx) exists in your struts-config file. If "action" is also defined, check if a method with the same name is present in your action. In case parameter is defined, but not present in parameters, you have to create a "unspecified" method in your action. If you don't use "parameter" in your struts-config file, use an "execute" method .

///////////////////

exemple with parameter defined in the strust config:

url: yoursite.com/mypage/myaction.html?method=test

```
<action
  path="/mypage/myaction"
  type="myfolder.action.MyAction"
  name="MyActionForm"
  validate="false"
  parameter="method"
  scope="request">
  <forward name="success" path="/view/yourfile.jsp"/>
</action>



public class MyAction{


 public ActionForward test (ActionMapping mapping,
         ActionForm actform,
         HttpServletRequest request,
         HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception { 

                 ...

  return mapping.findForward("success");

 }


}
```

//////////////////

exemple without parameter defined in the trusts config:

url: yoursite.com/mypage/myaction.html

```
<action 
  path="/mypage/myaction"
  type="myfolder.action.MyAction"
  name="MyActionForm"
  validate="false"
  scope="request">
  <forward name="success" path="/view/yourpage.jsp"/>
</action>


public class MyAction {


 public ActionForward execute (ActionMapping mapping,
         ActionForm actform,
         HttpServletRequest request,
         HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception { 

                 ...

  return mapping.findForward("success");

 }


}
```

Was my explanation clear ? :-)
不明点御座いましたら、遠慮なくきいて下さい～

Comment: thank you for the explanation. it really helped me a lot... :D i tried other options and it worked but what you gave me was way lot better. thanks... :D

Comment: happy to hear my comment helped you !